# Addition if identical value over line

Tags: bash, awk, grep

I have a CSV like:

```
1015,5
1015,4
1035,17
1035,11
1009,1
1009,4
1026,9
1004,5
1004,5
1009,1
```

I search a way to obtain : an addition of the second number if the first number match

```
1015,9
1035,28
1009,6
1026,9
1004,10
```

Comment: Post the code you've written so far. Do identical value lines always follow one after another or can they occur in a different order?

Comment: What is your question?  What is the code you have written so far?

Answer (score 4):

Try this :

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}{a[$1]+=$2}END{for(i in a){print i,a[i]}}' file
```

This is the [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) snippet that every shell coder should know from the top of his head.